# Padding issue with foundation 6 and top-bar with user avatar image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I have a nav-bar and trying to place the users name and profile picture in the nav-bar with a dropdown menu.  Its working fine except I cant get the padding/margins right to prevent it from making the top-bar larger when the image is there.  This is the html for the part of the top-bar with the user avatar and name (its a dropdown menu)

```
<div class="top-bar-right">
    <ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
        <li>
      <a class="avatar">
        <%= image_tag(current_user.avatar.present? ? current_user.avatar : "default-user.jpg", width: "40", height: "40") %>
        <span><%= current_user.displayname.present? ? current_user.displayname : current_user.firstname %></span>
      </a>
        <ul class="menu vertical">
          ......
            </ul>
    </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Ive tried adding various classes and editing the css but I cant seem to get rid of the padding that creates the extra space...I can make the image smaller but the size gets to small to prevent the padding making the bar larger.  Heres a screenshot of what i mean with the bar being too tall, you can see that there is a gap under the rest of the bar besides the image:

[image]

EDIT: Been playing around and still cant figure this out, Ive updated the screenshot with the inspect so you can see the specific html.  Also ive tried to add a class "avatar" and added this to my scss file:

```
a.avatar{
  padding-top: 500px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

but it doesnt change anything (tested with another element and it did change things)

EDIT 2: Figured it out...took awhile but I had to fully define the path in the css.  So it turned out to be this:

```
.dropdown.menu li.is-dropdown-submenu-parent a.avatar{
  padding-top: 0rem;
  padding-bottom: 0rem;
}
```

And that worked out perfectly....thanks for all the comments still

Comment: Right Click, "Inspect Element"

Comment: I did and it looks like its the <a> tag that is giving the extra padding, but when I assign a class to it doesnt take effect

Comment: Tried applying styles directly in the element inspector?

Comment: so I applied a class "user" and then added that to my stylesheet

Comment: set the li to absolute and the nav to relative. Or just set img to absolute and the a to relative maybe.

Comment: Uhhh, didnt do anything...I cant tell why but nothing I put in seems to affect that padding or placement

Comment: Ive made some edits to show what Ive been trying with no success